# project nested columns in mongodb

Tags: python, sql, mongodb

I have a collection in mongo where the data looks like this:

```
{
    "myinput": "myinput",
    "myoutput": {
        "Result": {
            "CrossData": {
                "CrossDto": [
                    {
                        "col1": "11",
                        "col2": "12",
                    },
                    {
                        "col1": "21",
                        "col2": "22",
                    },
                    {
                        "col1": "31",
                        "col2": "32",
                    }
                ],
                "ReqPartNumber": "myinput"
            }
        },
        "Status": {
            "Code": "0",
            "Message": "Successful Operation",
            "Success": "true"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to create a mapping table in SQL so the data will looks like this where CrossDto will only exist if Status is success:

```
myinput  11   12
myinput  21   22
myinput  31   32
...
```

I am trying to come up with a mongodb query to simply this on the query side as much as I can so I don't end up with crazy nested structure in Python to convert that into table format.

What I have done so far:

```
db.collection.find({'myoutput.Status.Success':'true'}, {_id:0, myoutput:1}).limit(1)
```

And it will select the records whose status is success and meanwhile, will only show the "myoutput"..

but what I want is actually a few levels deep, which is like this:

```
{
    "CrossDto": [
        {
            "col1": "1",
            "col2": "1",
        },
        {
            "col1": "2",
            "col2": "2",
        },
        {
            "col1": "3",
            "col2": "3",
        }
    ],
    "ReqPartNumber": "myinput"
}
```

Can anyone help me ? how can I configure the `projection` part of mongodb so I can get only the nest columns that I want... where I expect something similar like this:

```
{_id=0, myoutput.Result.CrossData=1}
```

Thanks `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this in MongoDB is to use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/). The framework is a pipeline that allows you to query and transform the data. In your case, you'll want this:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        'myoutput.Status.Success':'true'
    }
},
{
    $project: {
        'CrossDto': '$myoutput.Result.CrossData.CrossDto',
        'ReqPartNumber': '$myoutput.Result.CrossData.ReqPartNumber'
    }
})
```

Doing it in Python really isn't bad, and is how you'll have to do it if you have more data than the aggregation framework can handle:

```
myData = [doc['myoutput']['Result']['CrossData'] for doc in db.collection.find({'myoutput.Status.Success':'true'}, {_id:0, myoutput:1})]
```

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the answer, the logic makes sense to me.. but it triggers an error: `"errmsg" : "exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)",`

Comment: If you're getting that error that means you're working with more data (or larger documents) than the aggregation framework can handle. You'll have to do it in Python, but it shouldn't be too bad. I'll add how to do it in Python to my answer.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks so much... I can do it in Python myself.. but I will be interested to see your solution. If you can post some Python solution that works. I will accept your answer. vote up for now :)